# Trying to understand the logic of complex SQL queries in MySQL and relational algebra

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm working on a simple project to create tables and insert data into them, and finally execute some queries.  Please note: I'm using the MySQL command client.

My schema is easy to implement; it's no problem.

```
   Emp(eid: integer,  ename: string,  age: integer,  salary: real)
   Works(eid: integer,  did: integer,  pct_time: integer)
   Dept(did: integer,  budget: real,  managerid: integer)
```

**My first question:**

1. Find the department with the highest average age of employees.

When I first read the question, it seems easy. However while implementing I can't get the results. I have many queries like this, can someone explain the steps to make these queries easier?

I use the following query to get the avg ages of the all employees. The next step is to get the MAX age, but how?

```
> SELECT AVG(E.age) FROM DEPT D,EMP E,WORKS W  
> WHERE D.did=W.did and
> W.eid=E.eid  GROUP BY D.did
```

If you know any good books for just understanding these types of queries, that will be fine for me.

**Second question:**

Sometimes some instructors or database managers want the relational algebra of the queries?

Why is knowing the relational algebra of the queries important?

And can we all implement all these complex queries by using relational algebra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do yourself a favour and get a MySQL client with a GUI. It'll save you tons of time, especially when you're editing more complex queries.

I can recommend [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/), but there are plenty of other ones available for free.

Your first question:

```
select
  dept.did as `department`,
  avg(age) as `avgAge`
from
  dept,works,emp
where
  emp.eid=works.eid and 
  dept.did=works.did
group by
  dept.did
order by
  2 desc
limit 1
```

Maybe somebody else wants to do the rest of your homework for you.

Comment: thanks for your comment,it's not homework.i'm trying to do my best to learn. That's it.if it is homework, i can all past the questions and wait someone to solve them... anyway thanks alot.

Comment: actually when i look your query it seems not efficient some other options can be more efficient by using nested queries or not?

Comment: how can you tell it's not efficient?  You have no idea what the DBMS does with a query unless you look at it's execution plan.   Anyways, this query is pretty straightforward and hence should be fast so long as the database has decent indexes.

Comment: Actually i have basic knowledge in indexing, as i understand it just gets the avg ages of the 'all' employees and then restricts it by using the order by.

Answer (score 1):

You were close. Try this:

```
SELECT
    MAX(AVG(age)) AS Department_id_with_the_highest_average_age
FROM
    dept, emp, works
WHERE
    dept.did=works.did
    AND
    works.eid=emp.eid
GROUP BY dept.did
```

About Relational Algebra, read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Natural_join_.28.29)

Enjoy.

Comment: thanks for your answer but MAX(AVG(age)) can not be used together:)

Answer (score 1):

Answering to your three distinct "second questions" :

"Sometimes some instructors or database managers want the relational algebra of the queries?"

I wouldn't know about instructors, but I'm fairly certain database managers never will (alas).  They just want "the job done".  Oh wait, and they usually don't want to see any "exotic" queries emerge on their precious databases either.  If they do, they'll come and tell you something that basically means that you should *NOT* have used the full expressive power of the algebra in that query of yours they find so suspicious.  Sometimes with good reason, sometimes not.

Knowing the relational algebra of the queries, why important?

Because if you don't understand the algebra, you basically just don't have a clue about what your SQLs mean/do.  But that needn't worry you - the vast majority of so-called and more often than not self-proclaimed "database professionals" don't have a clue either and they can still make a living out of their ignorance.  Ask a dozen people in your environment whether anyone can tell you something sensible about generalized transitive closure and you'll see what I mean.

And can we all implement all these complex queries by using relational algebra?

Yes.  Relational algebra/Relational calculus (distinct but equivalent) are the foundation.  And they are commonly regarded as "expressively complete" (meaning : they are sufficient to express just any query one could possibly imagine).